# Error in template class

Tags: c++, templates, ubuntu, g++

Hi I am trying to build empty functions for templates so that I can later fill in the details. Here is my code:

```
namespace my {
    template <class T>
    class Sptr {
    private:
        //some kind of pointer
            //one to current obj
        T obj;
        size_t reference_count;
            //one to original obj
    public:
        template <typename U> Sptr(U *);
        Sptr(const Sptr &);
        //template <typename U> Sptr(const Sptr<U> &);
        ~Sptr();
        T* operator->() {return &obj;};
        template <typename U> Sptr<T> &operator=(const Sptr<U> &);
        //overload *,->,=,copy-constructor

        // const-ness should be preserved.
        // Test for null using safe-bool idiom
        // Static casting, returns a smart pointer
    };


    template <typename U> Sptr<U>::Sptr(U* u) {
        //do something
    }

    template <typename T> Sptr<T>::Sptr(const Sptr<T> &copyObj) {
        //do copy constructor stuff
    }

    template <typename T> Sptr<T>::Sptr& operator=(const Sptr<T> &T) {
        return *this;
    }
}
```

But I get the following error when I compile it.

```
Sptr.hpp:30:24: error: prototype for ‘my::Sptr<T>::Sptr(U*)’ does not match any in class ‘my::Sptr<T>’
Sptr.hpp:17:3: error: candidates are: my::Sptr<T>::Sptr(const my::Sptr<T>&)
Sptr.hpp:16:25: error:                 template<class T> template<class U> my::Sptr::Sptr(U*)
Sptr.hpp:38:24: error: ‘my::Sptr<T>::Sptr’ names the constructor, not the type
```

How do I solve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you define member functions of a class template is incorrect. Here is how you should define the constructor template:

```
template<typename T> // <== template parameter declaration for Sprt<T>
template<typename U> // <== template parameter declaration for constructor
Sptr<T>::Sptr(U* u) {
    //do something
}
```

And here is how you should define the `operator =`:

```
template <typename T> // <== template parameter declaration for Sprt<T>
template<typename U> // <== template parameter declaration for operator
Sptr<T>& Sptr<T>::operator=(const Sptr<U> &t) {
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename U> Sptr<U>::Sptr(U* u) {
    //do something
}
```

should be

```
template <typename T> 
   template <typename U>
       Sptr<T>::Sptr(U* u) {
        //do something
    }
```

similarly for the other member function templates.

Comment: could it be done as `template<typename T, typename U> Sptr<T>::Sptr(U* u)`?

Comment: @John: No, it's not a template with two template parameters. It's a function template within a class template

Answer (score 1):

You define both the constructor and `operator=` as template functions. I'm not sure you actually want that. Shouldn't they just be taking `T` as arguments? Are you sure you don't want this for your constructor declaration:

```
Sptr(T*);
```

If you really do want them to be function templates, this is incorrect:

```
template <typename U> Sptr<U>::Sptr(U* u) {
    //do something
}
```

When you have a function template inside a function class, you need to give both sets of template arguments:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
Sptr<T>::Sptr(U* u) {
    //do something
}
```